# Fine permanent fluorescent marker for blue light

Tags: microbiology, lab-techniques

I am looking for a fine- (or small-)tipped permanent marker to write on Petri dishes that is visible under a blue light or a transilluminator. It would seem obvious, but it is a nuisance.

- The Sharpie Neon series are too thick.
- Highlighters and all the arts pens I have tried rub off the polycarbonate.
- The red colour from Staedtler lumocolor (black body) shows up faintly —none of the other do— but too faintly.
- The Neon series from Staedtler triplus fineliner (gray body, triangular) rub off

So I would like to find what solutions other have come up with or if there is a brand that works well.

EDIT. This is how the Sharpie series look:
[image: Sharpie neon colors on transiluminator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem before... this is what I ended up using:
[https://www.amazon.com/Invisible-Blacklight-Marker-Blue-Yellow/dp/B004C89M9Q](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C89M9Q)

You may have to write on a tape or something so that the ink doesn't come off. (Ink may come off if you incubate plates)